# is it possible to detect when 3rd party push notification is shown while my app is on foreground Swift iOS

Tags: swift, notifications

When I am running my app at foreground is it possible to detect when 3rd party push notifications appear and dissapear?

I want to pause app work when 3rd party push notification appears and resume when 3rd party push notification dissapears.

I don't need neither the contents of 3rd party push notification neither 3rd party app name or etc, I need just fact that something like it interrupts my app screen and I want to resume work after it dissapears

I am on Swift 5 with SwiftUI and Xcode 11.3

Thanks in advance

Comment: If a notification appears as an alert, your app is not in the foreground. It is inactive. And that is something you can detect. If a notification is just a banner, your app is still foregrounded and interactive and you don’t need to know anything.

Comment: matt, what event is fired then? I tried to check sceneWillResignActive or sceneDidBecomeActive but they don't fire when some 3rd party notification is displayed on top of my app

Comment: matt, - If a notification is just a banner, your app is still foregrounded and interactive  - that is exactly I believe my case - i want to find out when these banner appears and pause app work then when banner dissapears resume work - if it is possible

Comment: You can't. You have no way of knowing that anything is happening.

Comment: okay, thanks for your answer